# How to pass an array of bytes reference to a COM object method

Tags: php, arrays, vb.net, com, variant

In PHP, I want to pass an array of bytes reference to a `COM` object method whose syntax in VB is:

```
object.VBObjectMethod(ByRef aRawData() As Byte)
```

where parameter `aRawData` is an array of bytes that specifies a data object.

In PHP I am initialising the `COM` class and calling `VBObjectMethod` as follows:

```
$theObject = new COM("VBObject.Class") or die ("Could not initialise VBObjectClass");
```

Up to this bit things are OK but I have no idea how to do the following correctly:

```
$theObject->VBObjectMethod("How do I pass a reference to a byte array here?");
```

I have a `$byteArray` I am passing to `VBObjectMethod` in PHP as follows;

```
$theObject->VBObjectMethod($byteArray);
```

But, I get the following Fatal error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Source:
> VBObject.Class 
> **Description:** Bad variable type.' in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\waterCompany\reservoir.php:3 Stack trace #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\waterCompany\reservoir.php(3):
> com->VBObjectMethod(Array)#1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\waterCompany\reservoir.php on line 3C:\xampp\htdocs\waterCompany\reservoir.php on line 3

Comment: maybe interesting? Pass a PHP `Variant` object?  [VARIANT class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.variant.php)  Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596490/pass-by-reference-to-com-object-in-php?

Comment: A PHP array is not the same as a VB array. Please show how `arawData()` is defined in VB.

Comment: @Parfait aRawData is an array of bytes that specifies a data object. It is the parameter that is passed in VBObjectMethod. That is how data should be passed in that method in VB. I am trying to pass byte array data to VBObjectMethod in Php. In VB I did so with a lot if ease but in Php I am stuck.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent that question link you shared and this other one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686624/building-a-byte-array-in-php-with-variants seem to edge me closer but I am still yet to figure out how to do it. I have tried the following without success $theObject->VBObjectMethod(new VARIANT($byteArray, VT_ARRAY)); $theObject->VBObjectMethod(new VARIANT($byteArray, VT_UI1)); $theObject->VBObjectMethod(new VARIANT($byteArray, VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1));